Can the new duplicate comment make "edit" a magic link
Recently the comment posted, when a question is voted/flagged as duplicate of another was changed (I can't find an announcement post for this, as I'd likely post this as an answer there if I could there was no announcement post for this, only an answer to a feature-request), which instead of reading:

Does this answer your question? [Question Link]

Now reads:

This question is similar to: [Question Link]. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Can the "edit" word be changed to be a "magic link" ([edit]) so that it is a link to edit the actual question? It is surprising how many users "struggle" to find it, or answer in the comments. It also makes it more consistent with the comment templates in the Staging Ground, as the Duplicate comment is the only one that doesn't make "edit" a magic link.

They announced it in an answer and a one line mention in We spent a sprint addressing your requests — here’s how it went

God, consistency. What a beautiful thing. I wish it was at the top of the bullet list for acceptance criteria.

As part of our Community Asks Sprint, this issue should be resolved now. The edit text within the comment is now a link to edit the post.

Thanks Troy. It's not that I don't believe you, but I've not VTC'd, or seen VTC, as duplicate without hammering since you posted this. As soon as I've seen it in action, I'll also mark this as the solution.
